# Font Awesome icon couldn't show issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I tried to using font-awesome icons but some icons show and others couldnt show. It gave me this error:

[image]

my usage :

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Load font awesome icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
...
some codes
...
</html>
<script>
...some code...
...
...
display data table: 
"data": null,
 "render": function (data, type, row)
           {
           if (row.detailPhysicalPath == "") {
         return '<button  id="' + row.staffCode+ '" onclick="captureClick(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa fa-camera"></i></button>';}
           else {
                return '<button  id="' + row.staffCode+ '" onclick="captureClick(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></button>';}
             }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem is the font awesome icon name that your using is version 4,
and You have included CDN  of font awsome version 5

**Font Awesome Version 5** :  **`<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>`**

**Example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">

<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
```

**Font Awesome Version 4** :  **`<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>`**

**Example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class name isn't `far fa fa-check-circle-o`.

The correct name is `fa fa-check-circle-o`.